# What does the "that" refer to?

Tags: relative-clauses, attachment-ambiguity

> You use *'of'* to combine two nouns when the first noun identifies the feature of the second noun that you want to talk about.

I am not sure what "I" want to talk about in the sentence.

Talking about "the feature" or talking about "the second noun"?

Comment: Honestly, the sentence would be perfectly fine without the word "that" between "noun" and "you".

Comment: I think "**the second noun that you want to talk about**" must be seen as a whole phrase.

Comment: Exactly. @Cardinal I parsed for the op that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case, take an example.

> *color of an elephant*

Two nouns - color and elephant. The first noun 'color' identifies the feature of the second noun 'elephant'.

Now go back to the sentence in concern: Read it this way-

> You use 'of' to combine two nouns when the first noun identifies the feature of [the second noun that you want to talk about].

So, to answer, here, you want to talk about 'the elephant' here.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer! I got it now, but I got another question again.what could I say if I want to make "that" refer to the first noun. E.g.,"the color that we talk about of an elephant".I am not sure if the sentence I made is correct or not.

Comment: Yes, placing 'that' in that way will talk about the color.

Comment: This is wrong - it's the *color* that you want to talk about - "...the first noun identifies the feature [...] that you want to talk about". Otherwise you can't have "the feature", because there's nothing to make it definite.